# Saving Decimal to SQL Server database using C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am working on an inventory application and I am trying to store the decimal of the "premium" we pay when we procure certain goods at auction. The percentage is being selected by a drop down, sent to an ASMX web service and then inserted into the database using a SQL Server stored procedure.

It appears everything is passing to the SQL Server stored procedure, but the value is being stored as "0" every time. The values I have tried have been .15 , .25 and .35. The column is set up as `decimal(18,0)` in SQL Server.

Here is my web method:

```
public string TestMethod(string SupplierName, string SupplierType, string SupplierLocation, decimal SupplierPremium)
{
    string _supplierName = SupplierName;
    string _supplierType = SupplierType;
    decimal _supplierPremium = Convert.ToDecimal(SupplierPremium);
    string _supplierLocation = SupplierLocation;

    // Database Connection
    using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
    {
        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertSupplier",myConnection))
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SupplierName",_supplierName));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SupplierType", _supplierType));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SupplierPremium", _supplierPremium));
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SupplierLocation", _supplierLocation));

            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 0 in 18,0 means no room for decimal numbers.

Comment: you've created a decimal field but then told it not to store anything after the decimal point!

Comment: Column defination is wrong, should have something like 18, 2 to provide space two decimal point.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I need more coffee. I should have caught that.